# Any emacs packages available for browsing databases (viewing schemas, running sql queries)?

Tags: emacs

I'm giving emacs a try for the first time and I was wondering if anyone has recommended strategy for connecting to databases (I regularly work with mysql, oracle, and sqlserver). I'm looking for a solution that would provide similar functionality to what phpmyadmin provides for mysql but available from within emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a [bunch of links](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySql) on emacswiki.

Comment: Thanks, John, I don't know how I missed that. I googled `emacs database` and `emacs db browser`. should-a googled `emacs sql`!

Comment: No problem,  I just found it the other day by browsing the wiki.